# ipython notebook css formatting of code cells

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, inspector

I'm using custom css in my notebook, but it seems that I haven't overwritten the default css properly. My code cells look like this:

[image: nice looking code cell]

When I execute them, they add some space at the bottom which seems to include the original input format:

[image: strange looking code cell]

I'd like to get rid of this.

Using firefox's Inspector, I can see that the `div.input_area` element is enlarged when compared to the same element in the cells below that haven't been executed:

[image: The problematic div]

The enlarged div is highlighted in faint blue, in the section titled 'Setting up'. The same element under the section 'Defining some helper functions' has the correct size.

Once I double click on the enlarged cell, it displays correctly again.

What causes the `div.input_area` element to increase in size or what could I do to find the cause?

**Edit:**

I just found out that the parent of `div.input_area` has a `-moz-box-flex: 1` property. When I untick this, the cell shrinks horizontally to fit content (which I don't want) but also covers the previously added extra space. It looks like this:

[image: Horizontally shrunken, but covering the extra space that has been added automatically after cell execution]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your modify css ? I can't see the behavior on my computer with default theme.
And I don't see any reason why the size of the `.input_area` should change seeing how it works. But I'm on master[*] and some css have been changed, so this might be the reason why.

As for  overwriting the css properly, there is no official way to do it, except with custom.css, but as our css is almost-fully compiled using `.less` you might want to just redefine a `variable.less` file and recompile your full `style.css` file to be sure to overwrite the color in all the right places.

Side note, we'd like to have easier theming for the notebook/nbviewer, but we don't have enough manpower to do that. Ideas, help and docs writing welcomed :-)

[*] or even on branches not merged on master most of the time

Comment: I uploaded the css file [here](https://github.com/panditarevolution/ipythonNotebook_customs/tree/master/monokai). I just put this together yesterday evening, so it's probably not terribly well organised, but there are some comments that might help. Most of the css regarding the input/output area is at the end of the file. Let me know if you have questions. Once I understand the css I'm happy to do a quick write-up of the things I learned, if this helps :). Cheers